# Recognize swipe gesture in UIView to scroll the scrollView using gesture-recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swipe-gesture

I have UIScrollView and the scroll view frame is not equal to the UIView frame. So, scroll view contents are not swiped while swiping outside the scroll view frame. But I want the whole screen responsive for the scroll view though the scroll view doesn't cover full screen. 
**I know that can be done by making the scroll view frame equal to the view frame**.But I don't want to do it. I tried other possible solutions I found so far. But nothing is working as I want. **I need to do this using gesture recognizer.**

Following is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:

                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:

                 scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true


            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

This is my view controller and the blue background is the scroll view. Swipe gesture works only on that blue region. But I want it to work through the screen even in corners. **How can I achieve it using gesture recognizer**?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43328905/5173807

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

I actually just learned about a much simpler solution: just add `view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)` to your `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

What this essentially does is take the `scrollView`'s [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer), a gesture recognizer that recognizes finger dragging and scrolls the `scrollView`'s content, and gives it to the base view so it can recognize finger dragging and scroll the `scrollView`'s content too.

So you don't need all the math and `scrollRectToVisible` as described below. Oh well, I think it's useful and fun to learn more about how UIScrollViews work!

**OLD**

To programmatically make the UIScrollView "scroll", use UIScrollView's `scrollRectToVisible`.

See **[Programmatically scroll a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234875/programmatically-scroll-a-uiscrollview)** for more details and code syntax.

Basically, at any point in time, a UIScrollView's *content subview* is offset some amount from its frame.

It helps to understand the parts to a UIScrollView (esp. the content subview), like in this picture (feel free to ignore the purple UIImageView): [image]

In the first image, the UIScrollView's content subview (red outline) is not offset from the UIScrollView's frame (assumed to be the same size as the visible screen) at all: both have the same top left corner at (0, 0).

In the second/middle image, the UIScrollView's content subview is now offset "up": the content subview's top left corner is at something like (0, -200) now, where (0, 0) is still the top left corner of the UIScrollView's frame.

Again, you can change the UIScrollView's content subview offset, and thus simulate a "scroll", using `scrollRectToVisible`, and the parameter `animated: true`.

*Hint*: to have the content scroll left (after the user swipes right-to-left) for example, you'd take the UIScrollView's current content offset's x coordinate (`scrollView.contentOffset.x`) and *subtract* the width of the UIScrollView (`scrollView.frame.size.width`) to it. So if the UIScrollView's current content offset (top-left corner) is (0, 0), the content offset (top-left corner) moves from (0-width, 0), and the content "moves" left.

Comment: One problem with the new method is that the pan gesture is now detected only on the outside view and not on the actual scrollview! So I used the method mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131986/scrollview-gesture-recognizer-swipe-vertically/43328905#43328905 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Make your scroll view to the view's frame, but then set the content inset/offset, so that it only goes until the blue frame

Comment: Also, if you want the blue background to only go until there, simply add a UIView with that background colour as a subview to your scrollview, but using the old frame (with the gap)